# TypeScript compile AMD modules with required defines

Tags: requirejs, typescript

In AMD (as implemented in requirejs) one can defined modules to be included as dependencies, eg:

```
define(['require','exports'], function(require, exports) {
  var externalDep = require('path/to/depModule');

  // Use the module somewhere.
});
```

I have tried the --module amd and it outputs correctly an AMD module usable by requirejs.

Is it possible to define dependencies inside the source of TypeScript source file that translates to something like the example above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to "export" your modules;

```
export module depModule { 
    export class A { 
    }
}
```

that will transalate into JavaScript code that looks like:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    (function (depModule) {
        var A = (function () {
            function A() { }
            return A;
        })();
        depModule.A = A;
    })(exports.depModule || (exports.depModule = {}));
})
```

and then you consume them by using "import":

```
module otherModule { 
    import  depModule = module('depModule');
    var a = new depModule.depModule.A();
}
```

you will need to specify the type of your module code generation to the compiler using --module AMD.

Comment: Nice answer, can you explain how to setup Visual Studio with this compiler parameter?

Comment: @Eric - I would suggest you install the 'Web Essentials 2012' extension of Mads Kristensen. In the options page of the extension you can specify that TypeScript files should be compiled with the AMD option. You can download/find it here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

Comment: It should be noted that as of version 3.0, all TypeScript support has been removed from Web Essentials, see the [change log](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog). This funtionality should be available in Visual Studio eventually.