# How can I call a function that's created inside a chain of other functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have created the following:

```
module Admin.Grid {
    export function addGridControls() {

        $('#createLink')
            .click(function () {
                var $link = $(this);
                $link.prop('disabled', true);
                adminDialog($link);
                return false;
            });
    }
}
```

This is converted to:

```
var Admin;
(function (Admin) {
    (function (Grid) {
        function addGridControls() {
            $('#createLink').click(function () {
                var $link = $(this);
                $link.prop('disabled', true);
                adminDialog($link);
                return false;
            });
```

Previously when it was not inside a module I called the function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    addGridControls()
});
```

Now it's inside of a module what's the best way for me to call this 
function so it gets executed every time the document is ready?

Comment: may be you need to import module `Admin.Grid` and call `Admin.Grid.addGridControls();`

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is, is to add the function to some object.

```
var Admin = {};
(function (Admin) {
    (function (Grid) {
        Admin.addGridControls = function () {
....
```

And call it like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    Admin.addGridControls()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike Lin has commented, you need to import the module.

Working in TypeScript (and assuming AMD module format, with your module in another file), you can do it like this:

```
import g = module('path-to-admin-grid-module');

$(document).ready(() => {
    "use strict";
    g.Admin.Grid.addGridControls();
});
```

Otherwise, if you're just using internal modules within the same file, it's as simple as:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
        "use strict";
        Admin.Grid.addGridControls();
});
```

The latter case is nicely previewed in the Walkthrough: Modules example here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/

There's a pretty good example of the former here: [TypeScript compile AMD modules with required defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706167/typescript-compile-amd-modules-with-required-defines) and AMD is covered in more detail here: http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html